# Spring setting WebApplicationContext in ServletContextAware bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I'm converting existing code to Spring 3 JDBC. I've put it into a class (SpringDB.Users) that implements ServletContextAware. In setServletContext(), the following code doesn't work:

```
public void setServletContext(ServletContext sc)
{
    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sc);
    simpleJdbcTemplate = (SimpleJdbcTemplate) wac.getBean("simpleJdbcTemplate");
}
```

The reason is: exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

However I did register a ContextLoaderListener in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The applicationContext.xml has this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql"/>
<bean id="simpleJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean class="SpringDB.Users"/>
```

which results in getting the call to setServletContext(). The class SpringDB.Users is mostly static stuff. It is never instantiated by the java code.

Apparently, the call to WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext() is "too early". Because what does work without any trouble is to get the WebApplicationContext at a later time, i.e. when database work really starts - so what I do is to call a private function getSimpleJdbcTemplate() instead of a private variable simpleJdbcTemplate:

```
static private SimpleJdbcTemplate getSimpleJdbcTemplate ()
{
    if (simpleJdbcTemplate == null)
    {
        WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        simpleJdbcTemplate = (SimpleJdbcTemplate) wac.getBean("simpleJdbcTemplate");
    }
    return simpleJdbcTemplate;
}
```

Is there any solution so that the variable simpleJdbcTemplate can be initialized within `setServletContext()` ?

Am I missing something obvious, or just expecting too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need that in the first place?

If your class is a bean, then you can simply inject (with `@Inject`, `@Autowired` or xml) the jdbc template:

```
@Inject
private SimpleJdbcTemplate template;
```

Comment: Doesn't compile because "non-static variable template cannot be referenced from within a static context". As I said, the class is never instantiated. As a static variable, "Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields". I'm aware I could probably solve the problem by simply doing a getBean() within the calling bean but I'm trying not to change the code outside of the database bean.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr well, of course - get rid of all static context. Why do you need it?

Comment: Because I was trying not to change the existing code outside of the database bean. That code never instantiates the database classes, it just uses static calls, these classes didn't even have any variables. Yes, your suggestion would work in a class with a non-static variable. I'm aware that static calls are normally a no-no as per "clean code" teaching, but I'm trying to improve existing code slowly.(more in next comment)

Comment: However I did come up with a solution:
        <bean class="SpringDB.Users">
        <property name="SimpleJdbcTemplate" ref="simpleJdbcTemplate"/>
    </bean>

together with

    public void setSimpleJdbcTemplate (SimpleJdbcTemplate template)
    {
        simpleJdbcTemplate = template;
    }

did it. So thanks, sortof :-)